# Hot to read the file from non-public storage folder

Tags: php, laravel, security, backend, storage

I want to store files in non-public storage folder and I want to display in a front. It would be security against unauthorized access. I know that I can use `readfile` function but it doesn't work, for example:

`readfile('/private/something.jpg')`

Could you show me code or other method to display file from non-public storage folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel, you can store files in a non-public storage folder and display them securely on the front end by using the Storage facade.'

step-by-step guide:
Step 1 : we're creating a new disk named "private" that will store files in a non-public directory located at storage/app/private. We're also setting the visibility to "private" so that the files will not be directly accessible from the web.

```
'disks' => [
    // ...
    'private' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/private'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'private',
    ],
],
```

Step 2 :
Store the file using the putFileAs() method:

```
$file = $request->file('file');
$path = $file->storeAs('private', $file->getClientOriginalName(), 'private');
```

Step 3 :
Generate a temporary URL for the file:

```
$url = Storage::disk('private')->temporaryUrl($path, now()->addMinutes(10));
<a href="{{ $url }}">Download File</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `disk` method on the `Storage` facade to specify the disk you want to use.

you can use the following code:

```
$fileContents = Storage::disk('local')->get('my_directory/file.txt');
```

**Note** that you have to specify the disk you want to use, as by default Laravel uses the `public` disk which allows access to public files.